# How to toggle all but selected elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to do the following:

- There are multiple "title" and "text" divs on a page.
- Upon loading the page only the first text is visible.
- When clicking on any title, its text slides down and all other texts slide up.

So far I came up with the following:
HTML:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.title').click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e3okos3e/

However, this is very basic.

Can you tell me how to select every text other than the selected title's one?
How to make only the first one visible at loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly straightforward using `not()`

```
var $text = $('.text');// cache elements

$('.title').click(function () {
    var $next = $(this).next().slideDown();// or slideToggle()
    $text.not($next).slideUp();
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/e3okos3e/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

So, if all of the `text` divs are hidden by default, then do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.title').click(function () {
    $('.active').slideToggle().removeClass('active');
    $(this).next().slideToggle().addClass('active');
  })
});
```

```css
.title {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #cc0;
  }
.text {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="text">text1</div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="text">text2</div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="text">text3</div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="text">text4</div>
</div>
```